# How did they apply the quotient rule here to get this simplication?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image]

by the quotient rule, shouldn't it be $$v'(x)=\frac{u(y)u'(x+y)-u(x+y)u'(y)}{u(y)^2}=0?$$ How are they getting $v(x)$?

Comment: $y$ is a constant and so is $u(y)$. You are differentiating w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: In fact they're doing $$\left(\frac{u(x+y)}{u(y)}\right)'=\frac1{u(y)}\left(u(x+y)\right)'=\ldots$$ as they're differentiating wrt $x$ and thus $\;u(y)\;$ is a like a constant, and thus not the quotient rule at all...unless it was given that $\;y\;$ is a function of $x$, which is not.